# C# WPF edit datagrid cell colour based on data length

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, datagrid, cell

I have a datagrid and if the cell text is over 32 characters, i want to make the cell red.

I've seen other solutions based on when the cell text is certain text but i'm not sure how to go about using those solutions here

my XAML is as follows

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="2" Name="DataGridView1" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Background="LightGray" RowBackground="#BDBDBF" AlternatingRowBackground="#E3E3E5"></DataGrid>
```

To put my data in i read it into a DataTable called dt and do as follows.

```
DataGridView1.DataContext = dt.DefaultView;
```

**UPDATE**

Using some code from Daniel W. i have got it to partially work, i just need the finishing touches now.

I have got it to work for 1 column by doing the following:

```
  <DataGrid  Grid.Row="2" Name="DataGridView1" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Background="LightGray" RowBackground="#BDBDBF" AlternatingRowBackground="#E3E3E5">
            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Address1}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Address1, Converter={StaticResource brushConverter}}">
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

However this does mess up the formatting of my datatable

https://i.gyazo.com/525ce05a30cad36458a6734d6c61a0ff.png

As you can see the 'address1' column i want editing is not edited, but rather a new column is made to the left of the regular columns.

Now, i cant define each column as the column name can change at run time so i wont know what i'm binding it to

I need a solution that will just act as a template as my columns aren't defined until i read in the csv which can have any number of columns / names so i cant do data binding to these columns

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

## Manual defined colums

You can use a converter bound to the Foreground/Background converting String based on length:

```
public class LengthToBrush : IValueConverter
{
    private const int _colorBorders = 0;
    private const int _pow = 2;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var stringValue = value as String;
        if (stringValue == null || stringValue.Length <=32) return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Add the converter  to the resources

```
<Window.Resources>
    <converters:LengthToBrush x:Key="brushConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

And use it in the colum definition

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="2" Name="DataGridView1" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Background="LightGray" RowBackground="#BDBDBF" AlternatingRowBackground="#E3E3E5">
        <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Foreground="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource brushConverter}}"/>


        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

## Auto generated colums

If you want to use auto generated colums you must use a style for the DataGridCell

for this a different converter is needed, returning true in case foreground should be red:

```
public class LengthToBool : IValueConverter
{
    private const int _colorBorders = 0;
    private const int _pow = 2;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var stringValue = value as String;            
        if (stringValue == null || stringValue.Length > 12) return true;
        return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The style can be defined in the xaml file:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:LengthToBool x:Key="lengthConverter"/>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, 
                       Path=Content.Text, Converter={StaticResource lengthConverter}}" Value="True" >
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            </DataTrigger>
</Window.Resources>
```

The definition of the Data Grid can be done simple:

```
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="2" Name="DataGridView1" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" Background="LightGray" RowBackground="#BDBDBF" AlternatingRowBackground="#E3E3E5">

    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Hello,


I've done this but this hasnt worked because i dont usually define the datacolumns in the xaml, i instead read in a csv as a datatable and put this datatable into the datagrid


This is because the csv can have any number of columns with any name


So this code has just added a blank column called 'Name'

Comment: I updated m answer to explain how this can be done with style for auto generated colums